# In the fork() process, child clearly gets a new kernel stack, but fork() man pages fails to mention that?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, stack, fork

I was going through the `fork()` process and the steps executed mainly to get a detailed view of what is and what is not shared between the parent and the child process.

So in the `dup_task_struct()` function I can clearly see that it is allocating a new stack using `alloc_thread_stack_node()` (although on the same numa node as the parent), and it is then assigning it to the would be created child process `task_struct`

```
stack = alloc_thread_stack_node(tsk, node);
.
.
tsk->stack = stack;
```

This means that the parent and the child does not share the kernel stack..

But as I went through the [man pages of `fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), to confirm my findings, I failed to find any mention of such info.

There is a section which says the things that parent and child does not share

> The child process is an exact duplicate of the parent process except
>          for the following points:

but it does not mention the kernel stack.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man pages in **Linux Programmer's Manual** describe things from the point of view of **application**'s developers.

From that point there is only **user part** of the process (which runs code in *user-space* mode), and only those attributes are described which relates to the user process.

Description of the kernel state is out of scope of that man pages. Moreover, `fork` is a part of POSIX standard, and Linux is not the only OS which implements this standard. Other OS'es may have another kernel part, which behaves differently on `fork`.